# TopAppBar and padding (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a slightly different expectation for padding to work. How can this problem be solved? I see this only at TopAppBar.

```kotlin
    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        title = { Text(title) },
        modifier = Modifier.statusBarsPadding(), //  or padding(top = 24.dp)
        actions = {
            if (isSync) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { },
                    enabled = false,
                    content = {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_outline_cloud_download_24),
                            contentDescription = title,
                            tint = Color.DarkGray.copy(alpha = alpha)
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        },
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
    )
```

[image]

**UPD**

For example, here it works as it should -> [link](https://qiita.com/Nabe1216/items/0823dc7ebfb5d616f9c1)

Answer (score 1):

I made it myself based on the source code. Not quite universal, but just right for me. I will not give the full code, it is in the source code. I will give only the place where it is necessary to add.

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun TopAppBarLayout(...) {
   Layout(
      ...,
      modifier = modifier.statusBarsPadding()
   ) {
       ...
   }
}
```

The rest of the code is identical to the original.

**UPDATE 21**

Now everything works out of the box.